# GHC cannot deduce (a1 ~ a) with GADTs and existential types

Tags: haskell

My code does not compile:

```
{-# LANGUAGE EmptyDataDecls, GADTs, RankNTypes  #-}

import Data.Ratio

data Ellipsoid
data Halfplane

data PointSet a where
    Halfplane :: RealFrac a => a -> a -> a -> (a -> a -> Bool) -> a -> PointSet Halfplane
    Ellipsoid :: RealFrac a => a -> a -> a -> (a -> a -> Bool) -> a -> PointSet Ellipsoid

type TestFunc =  RealFrac a => (a -> a -> a ->  Bool)

ellipsoid :: PointSet Ellipsoid -> TestFunc
ellipsoid (Ellipsoid a b c f r) = f' where f' z y x = ((x/a)^2 + (y/b)^2 + (z/c)^2) `f` r

halfplane :: PointSet Halfplane -> TestFunc
halfplane (Halfplane a b c f t) = f' where f' z y x = (a*x + b*y + c*z) `f` t
```

The error I get is:

```
Could not deduce (a1 ~ a)
[...]
Expected type: a -> a -> a -> Bool
  Actual type: a1 -> a1 -> a1 -> Bool
In the expression: f'
[...]
```

for both functions `ellipsoid` and `halfplane`.

I don't understand and am looking for an answer, why `a` cannot be equated with `a1`, both being `RealFrac`, or even better: why two different types (`a ~ a1`) are deduced?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your use of `GADT` with implicit `forall` is causing you grief. This is a good time to mention the "existential quantification with typeclass" [anti-pattern](http://lukepalmer.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/haskell-antipattern-existential-typeclass/)

Since you've included the constraint `RealFrac a` in the definition of `PointSet` you're implicitly using `forall` like this:

```
data PointSet a where
    Halfplane :: forall a. RealFrac a => a -> a -> a -> (a -> a -> Bool) -> a -> PointSet HalfPlane
    Ellipsoid :: forall a. RealFrac a => ...
```

The same applies to `TestFunc`:

```
type TestFunc = forall a. RealFrac a => a -> a -> a -> Bool
```

This is why GHC coerced you into adding the `RankNTypes` extension.

Because of `forall` the `a` in the constructors for `PointSet` cannot possibly unify with the `a` in `TestFunc` since the `a` in `PointSet` is some *specific* instance of `RealFrac`, but `TestFunc` is a function that is required to work for *any* `a`.

This difference between the specific type `a` and the universally quantified `forall a. a` causes GHC to deduce two different types `a` and `a1`.

The solution? Scrap all this existential nonsense. Apply the typeclass constraints ***where** and **when** they're needed*:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, GADTs, KindSignatures #-}

data Shape = Halfplane | Ellipsoid -- promoted via DataKinds

data PointSet (s :: Shape) a where
    Halfplane :: a -> a -> a -> (a -> a -> Bool) -> a -> PointSet Halfplane a
    Ellipsoid :: ...

type TestFunc a = a -> a -> a -> Bool

ellipsoid :: RealFrac a => PointSet Ellipsoid a -> TestFunc a
ellipsoid (Ellipsoid a b c f r) = f' where f' = ...
```

Now `PointSet` takes 2 parameters: a phantom type `s :: Shape` which has kind `Shape` (kinds are the types of types) and `a` which is the same as your original example, except as an explicit argument to `PointSet` it is no longer implicitly existentially quantified.

To address your last point, the `a` and `a1` in the error message are not "both being `RealFrac`. `RealFrac` is not a type, it is a typeclass. `a` and `a1` are two *potentially distinct* types that both happen to be instances of `RealFrac`.

**That said**, unless you are making use of the more expressive type of `PointSet` there is a much simpler solution.

```
data PointSet a
    = Halfplane a a a (a -> a -> Bool) a
    | Ellipsoid a a a (a -> a -> Bool) a

testFunc :: RealFrac a => PointSet a -> TestFunc a
testFunc (Ellipsoid a b c f r) = f' where f' = ...
testFunc (Halfplane a b c f t) = f' where f' = ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, I'm still lacking complete understanding. a) You write: "because of forall the a in the constructors for PointSet cannot possibly unify with the a in TestFunc, so the two different types a and a1 are deduced." -- I am not versed with System F, and this is my fault, but I don't see how the two are different and cannot unify. They seem quite equal to me. b) In your proposed solution, you did not only trash the constraint, but introduced the type variable `s` as well. Did I confuse the interpreter by setting my `a` implicitly via the `-> PointSet Halfplane`?

Comment: @ASz The `a`s can't unify precisely because they are universally quantified. The functions `forall a . a -> a` and `(forall a . a) -> (forall a . a)` are extremely different (the first is `id`, the second is `unsafeCoerce`). In other words, the `a` inside of `HalfPlane` is some specific `a`, but which one is unknown - all you know about it is its an instance of `RealFrac`. But `TestFunc` demands that the function be of *any* type `a`, which you don't have. Not sure what you mean in b).

Comment: CDK, If you add information from @user2407038's comment, which answers some of my lacking understanding to your answer, I will happily accept it as an answer.

Comment: @ASz: I've addressed your comments in my edited answer.

Comment: @cdk: sorry for the late acceptance... I'm just doing "spring cleaning" on my stackexchange accounts, and noticed that I did not accept the answer so far.